# Error when using ggcoxfunctional() on a model that includes splines

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I'm having an issue with using [ggcoxfunctional()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survminer/versions/0.4.9/topics/ggcoxfunctional) from `library(survminer)`but *only* after I use splines in my model. Without splines, and even with additions like frailty.gamma(), it works. I'm struggling to see why there would be an issue.

I'm using the coxph() model from `library(survival)`.

```
fit3 <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop_x, status == 1) ~ pspline(x1)+ pspline(x2), data)

ggcoxfunctional(spline_fit, data)
```

I then get the following error: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`.